# Integration with floor function

Tags: real-analysis, integration, definite-integrals

I can't find the exact value of the following integral:
$$\int\limits_0^1 {[ax][bx]} dx$$
where $a$ and $b$ have as greatest common divisor 1.
(gcd(a,b)=1)
Thanks.

Comment: This is the raw question. Are you asking us to serve you an answer on a silver tray ? What have you done on the subject ? Where are you blocked ?

Comment: A hint: Think to a particular case $a=3$, $b=7$, for example.  [ax] and [bx] being step functions, their product is also a step function with  jumps occuring (irregularly) at certain multiples of  $s=1/ab=1/21$. Subdivide then the integration interval $[0,1]$ into intervals of size multiple of $s$...

Comment: oK, I'm in the following step : $$\int\limits_0^1 {[ax][bx]} dx = \sum\limits_{n = 1}^{ab - 1} {[{a \over n}][{b \over n}]} $$

Comment: Comments: 1) not [a/n][b/n] but [n/a][n/b]. 2) You need to multiply your sum by the length $1/(ab)$ of the rectangular "bricks" 3) I don't believe (I am maybe wrong) that there is a closed form formula for the summation $\Sigma$ you will obtain.

Comment: There is a closed formula, and exuse me i forgot 1/ab after changing variables in the integral.

Comment: You mean you have been said that there is a closed formula: fine, please tell me when you have the solution...

Comment: $${1 \over {12ab}}(4{a^2}{b^2} - 3ab(a + b) - {a^2} - {b^2} + 3ab + 1)$$ using Fourier series....

Comment: Are you looking for an alternate solution to get this closed formula?

Comment: Thanks to you and to @user125932

Answer (score 2):

As mentioned in the comments, we have

$$\int_0^1 \lfloor ax \rfloor \lfloor bx \rfloor \, dx = \frac{1}{ab} \sum_{n=0}^{ab-1} \lfloor n/a \rfloor \lfloor n/b \rfloor $$

We'll work with residues mod $a$ and $b$ instead of the floor function. We can write $\lfloor n/a \rfloor = n/a - \{n/a\}$, where $\{x\}$ denotes the fractional part of $x$, and this satisfies $\{n/a\} = (n \mbox{ mod } a)/a$ for $n, a \in \mathbb{Z}$, $a > 0$, so $\lfloor n/a \rfloor = (n - (n \mbox{ mod } a))/a$. Then our sum becomes

$$\frac{1}{a^2b^2} \sum_{n=0}^{ab-1} (n - (n \mbox{ mod } a)) (n - (n \mbox{ mod } b))$$

We can break this into four sums. First,

$$\sum_{n = 0}^{ab-1} n^2 = \frac{(ab-1)ab(2ab-1)}{6}$$

By the Chinese Remainder Theorem, each pair of a residue mod $a$ and a residue mod $b$ corresponds to a unique residue mod $ab$, so

$$\sum_{n=0}^{ab-1} (n \mbox{ mod } a)(n \mbox{ mod } b) = \left( \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} k \right) \left( \sum_{l=0}^{b-1} l \right) = \frac{ab(a-1)(b-1)}{4}$$

Now $n = a\lfloor n/a \rfloor + (n \mbox{ mod } a)$, so

\begin{align*}
\sum_{n=0}^{ab-1} n (n \mbox{ mod } a) 
&= a \sum_{n=0}^{ab-1} \lfloor n/a \rfloor (n \mbox{ mod } a) + \sum_{n=0}^{ab-1} (n \mbox{ mod } a)^2 \\
&= a \left( \sum_{l=0}^{b-1} l \right) \left( \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} k \right) + b \sum_{k=0}^{a-1} k^2 \\
&= \frac{a^2 b (a-1)(b-1)}{4} + \frac{b(a-1)a(2a-1)}{6}
\end{align*}

and similarly $\sum_{n=0}^{ab-1} n (n \mbox{ mod } b) = \frac{ab^2 (a-1)(b-1)}{4} + \frac{a(b-1)b(2b-1)}{6}$, so our sum is

$$\frac{1}{a^2b^2} \left( \frac{(ab-1)ab(2ab-1)}{6} + \frac{ab(a-1)(b-1)}{4} - \frac{a^2 b (a-1)(b-1)}{4} - \frac{b(a-1)a(2a-1)}{6} - \frac{ab^2 (a-1)(b-1)}{4} - \frac{a(b-1)b(2b-1)}{6}\right)$$ 
which simplifies to $\frac{1}{12ab}(4a^2 b^2 - 3ab(a+b-1) - a^2 - b^2 + 1)$.

Comment: [+1] Very interesting.